# Can Blender be an alternative to Zbrush?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, sculpting

Blender has nice sculpting tools. Dynamic topology, variety of brushes and texture paint make it really nice sculpting software. But can it be an alternative to Zbrush? Can I make good looking hi-poly models without lots of annoyance?
While I find many Blender tutorials about making characters, I didn't find any for 3D textures. For example - can I make something like this in Blender - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR12Ja51iRs ?

And is it possible to make an UV map for hi-poly model without loosing stability? I've tried make an UV to hi-poly rock - Blender has frozen and I had to close it.

Comment: It can, but it is of course not as good, or as easy as Z-Brush, since it is dedicated solely to sculpting. I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based. In future things like this should be put on BlenderArtists :)

Comment: An important note about stability is that all software can become unstable, I have ZBrush and over the years it has crashed plenty and horribly. The sane approach is to save often and save using sequential files names (memory is almost free these days), this applies to Blender and all software... If you want to avoid redoing stuff.